# In tensorflow c++ api, how to save a picture or an array from a tensor

Tags: c++, opencv, tensorflow, eigen

I am trying to run a saved model for image segmentation, using tf 1.5.0 c++ api.
My model gets an input image with size 1*256*256*3, and feeds to a tensor like this:

```
  for (int x = 0; x < 256; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y <256; y++) {
      data_(0, x, y, 0) =
          (float) image_out.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y)[0];
      data_(0, x, y, 1) =
          (float) image_out.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y)[1];
      data_(0, x, y, 2) =
          (float) image_out.at<cv::Vec3b>(x, y)[2];
    }
  }
```

Then I run the model using `sess->Run()`, and get the output:

> input Tensor type: float shape: [1,224,224,3] values: [[[254 254
>   254]]]... Output  Tensor type: float shape: [1,224,224,1] values:
>   [[[0.160249829][0.0639446825][0.0414313935]]]...

I want to save the out put to a image using cv::imwrite(). However, a tensor can't be saved directly. So I tried to convert the tensor like this: tensorflow::tensor->eigen::mat->cv::mat. Code is:

```
auto m = Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<
             float,           /* scalar element type */
             Eigen::Dynamic,  /* num_rows is a run-time value */
             Eigen::Dynamic,  /* num_cols is a run-time value */
             Eigen::RowMajor  /* tensorflow::Tensor is always row-major */
              >>(
                 outputs[0].flat<float>().data(),  /* ptr to data */
                 outputs[0].dim_size(1),           /* num_rows */
                 outputs[0].dim_size(2)            /* num_cols */);

  //std::cout << "m " << m << std::endl;

  cv::Mat rotMatrix;
  cv::eigen2cv(m, rotMatrix);
```

This raises an error when compiling:

> note: template void cv::eigen2cv(const Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols>&, cv::Mat&)  void eigen2cv( const Eigen::Matrix<_Tp, _rows, _cols, _options, _maxRows,
>   _maxCols>& src, Mat& dst )
>         ^ /usr/local/opencv3.1/include/opencv2/core/eigen.hpp:63:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>   src/demo/demo.cpp:152:28: note:
>   \u2018Eigen::Map >\u2019 is not
>   derived from \u2018const Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols,
>   _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols>\u2019    cv::eigen2cv(m, rotMatrix);
>                               ^ In file included from src/demo/demo.cpp:11:0:
>   /usr/local/opencv3.1/include/opencv2/core/eigen.hpp:81:6: note:
>   template void cv::eigen2cv(const Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows,
>   _Cols, _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols>&, cv::Matx<_Tp, m, n>&)  void eigen2cv( const Eigen::Matrix<_Tp, _rows, _cols, _options, _maxRows,
>   _maxCols>& src,
>         ^ /usr/local/opencv3.1/include/opencv2/core/eigen.hpp:81:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
>   src/demo/demo.cpp:152:28: note:
>   \u2018Eigen::Map >\u2019 is not
>   derived from \u2018const Eigen::Matrix<_Scalar, _Rows, _Cols,
>   _Options, _MaxRows, _MaxCols>\u2019    cv::eigen2cv(m, rotMatrix);
>                               ^ make: *** [obj/demo.o] Error 1

What's the matter?

On the other hand, I don't think this is a good way to get the picture from a tensor. I've sacnned the tf's c++ api doc, and didn't find a good way. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/tensor#classtensorflow_1_1_tensor_1a6afab48885080a80ff0b52437959d929

So, is there a convenient way to do this?

Comment: did you find a solution for your question? I have the same issue, and I am looking for the answer too. So, if yes. Please, publish the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can directly wrap tensor data with OpenCV matrix header this way:

```c++
cv::Mat rotMatrix(outputs[0].dim_size(1), outputs[0].dim_size(2), CV_32FC1, outputs[0].flat<float>().data())
```

Comment: I tried this way and the result of is 1d array, not the segmented image.

Comment: @Zaher88abd, matrix shape is specified by the first two arguments. In the code sample above I use dimensions #1 and #2 of the tensor. Of course it depends on the tensor layout (if it includes batch dimension and if channels dimension is in the beginning or in the end). So you need to adjust `cv::Mat` definition according to your tensor.